# ЕСИА, Spring Boot, Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, есиа

Стоит задача привязать rest приложение, написанное на Spring Boot к ЕСИА, чтобы работа клиента с ним шла через bearer token.

По требованию заказчика, авторизация должна инициализироваться от именно приложения rest, а не от PHP клиента.

То есть надо сконфигурировать соответствующим образом AuthenticationManager, чтобы была возможность сначала авторизоваться, потом выбрать нужную организацию и вернуть токен.

Ну и конечно потом соответствующим образом сконфигурировать SecurityContext.

У кого-нибудь есть опыт подобных задач, возможно ли такое с ЕСИА и если да, то не поделится сообщество опытом?

Comment: как вопрос решился?